# Unreasonable undefined method `email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a repo that imitates Evernote, and I have established the relationship between the models and their respective columns. Among them, I rely on the column email in the model User to identify the user.

However, when I try to print `<%= note.user.email %>` in index.html.erb, I get an "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass" error. I don't understand, I have established valid `has_many` and `belongs_to`, and `email` is also an actual column. `note` is derived from the entity variable @note in the controller (where other fields are valid), I don't understand which link is wrong.

This is part of the schema

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "nickname"
    t.string "password"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

This is part of model User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :nickname, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true

  before_create :encrypt_password

  has_many :notes
```

This is model Note

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

  default_scope { where(deleted_at: nil) }

  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is part of NotesController

```
  def index
    @notes = Note.includes(:user).order(id: :desc)
  end
```

this is index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
  <% @notes.each do |note| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= note.user.email %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to note.title, note_path(note) %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "TO EDIT", edit_note_path(note) %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "TO DELETE", note_path(note), method: 'delete', data: { confirm: "確定嗎？" } %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass"

This error means you are looking for the method `email` on a nilClass object which mean your `note.user` is nil.

Rails can't find any user related to the note. You can first check if your `note` as a `user`.

Also you should check if you have a column `user_id` in your Note model it's needed for making the `belongs_to` relationship working. You probably did something like this in your note migration:

```rb
  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.belongs_to :user
    ...
  end
```

If you want your view to keep rendering and ignore the error if a note doesn't have any user you can do like this.

```html
<% if note.user.present? %>
 <td>
   <%= note.user.email %>
 </td>
<% end %>
```

or even using the [safe navigation operator](https://fullstackheroes.com/tutorials/ruby/safe-navigation-operator/) but it has its pros & cons

```html
<td>
  <%= note.user&.email %>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, ```<%= note.user&.email %>``` is valid, inaddition, my model Note include this ```t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_notes_on_user_id"```

Comment: If you want to actually solve the underlying problem make sure the `notes.user_id` is not nullable and that you have a foreign key constraint.